# Loading to trans tags in Djangocms-text-ckeditor

Tags: python, html, django, django-cms

I am using the `djangocms-text-ckeditor` plugin to add text to my pages but am having one issue which relates to translations.

Currently I have added the `load i18n` at the top but whenever I am using the text plugin and switch to source and directly type the HTML e.g. `<h1>{% trans "My Heading" %}</h1>`, it only shows `{% trans "My Heading" %}.

It renders it as it is.

Any help on how to use the `trans` tag inside the text plugin and get it to render correctly will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This snippet might help you out: [render_as_template template tag](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1373/)

I haven't tested it and you have to be aware about some security concerns.